# Exclude a subpath in find command

Tags: linux, unix, find

I have the following `find` command:

```
find /mnt/F_11 -type f \( -iname '*.xls' -o -iname '*.xlsx' /)
```

How would I find all items in `/mnt/F_11` but not in `/mnt/f_11/DONOTENTER/`?

In other words, I would want it to search:

```
YES /mnt/F_11
YES /mnt/F_11/somepath/
YES /mnt/F_11/somepath/other/
NO  /mtn/F_11/DONOTENTER/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-prune` to avoid recursing down branches you don't want to follow.

```
find /mnt/F_11 -name DONOTENTER -prune -o \
     -type f \( -iname '*.xls' -o -iname '*.xlsx' \) -print
```

Note the explicit `-print` at the end -- this is important, as otherwise the implicit print action covers both branches.

Comment: would that be faster than doing `-not -path /mnt/F_11/DONOTENTER*` ?

Comment: Yes, because `-prune` stops recursion down a path, whereas the other approach given would test contents within that subtree.